# "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" when Dynamically Resizing 2D Array

Tags: javascript

I would like to read some text, consisting of triads of comma separated numbers with one triad per line, into a 2D array.   I do not know in advance what the array dimensions will be.  I use the following code.

```
        // Read data into a matrix
        var inputData = [[]];
        while (allTextLines.length>0) {
            dataRecord=allTextLines.shift();
            entries = dataRecord.split(',');
            var xCoord=parseInt(entries.shift());
            var yCoord=parseInt(entries.shift());
            var zCoord=parseInt(entries.shift());
            if (yCoord>=inputData.length) inputData[yCoord]=[];
            inputData[yCoord][xCoord]=zCoord;
        }
```

This results in

```
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

from Firebug when I try to call

```
            if (yCoord>=inputData.length) inputData[yCoord]=[];
```

or

```
            inputData[yCoord][xCoord]=zCoord;
```

I thought that JavaScript arrays could be dynamically resized by assigning a value to an index higher than the current size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can be dynamically resized **when they exist**. There's no such thing as a 2D array in JavaScript. What you create in your initialization is a 1D array with an array in the first element.

All you have to do is check the first dimension before adding something in the second dimension. You're almost doing that now, so it's a minor change:

```
if (inputData[yCoord] == null) inputData[yuCoord] = [];
```

You have to do that instead of just checking the length because, if "yCoord" is initially 3, then positions 0, 1, and 2 would still be null after you initialize position 3.  Subsequently, a "yCoord" value of 2 would fail your length check, but the slot would be empty nevertheless.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
for (var yplus = inputData.length; yplus <= yCoord; inputData[yplus++] = []);
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks very much!  I can also understand your explanation of the problem.  I will accept the answer when I can.